# How to convert bitmap to byte array and byte array to bitmap in android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, bitmap

I convert bitmap to byte array and byte array to bitmap but when I have to show converted byte array in ImageView then it will show image with black corners not show in PNG format. I want to show image in PNG format, how can I do that??

[image: Image display after convert byte array to bitmap]

Here is a code for bitmap to byte array conversion and byte array to bitmap:

Bitmap into byte array in PNG compressed format:

```
public byte[] convertBitmapToByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = null;
    try {
        stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

        return stream.toByteArray();
    }finally {
        if (stream != null) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(Helper.class.getSimpleName(), "ByteArrayOutputStream was not closed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and convert byte array to bitmap as:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
```

Comment: @Prem that's not show image in png format. Show image with black png spaces

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this code

```
//For encoding toString
public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}
//For decoding
String str=encodedImage;
byte data[]= android.util.Base64.decode(str, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
public String convertBitmapToString(Bitmap bmp){
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream); //compress to which format you want.
        byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
        String imageStr = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);
        return imageStr;
    }
```